# Am I Hearing Bansuri Tune Correctly

Tags: ear-training, indian-classical, bansuri, saptak

I am learning to play [Tum Hi Ho](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Umqb9KENgmk) via [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNIhd3-TpNU)

Harsh Dave sings out the saptak (he doesn't write it), hence there is a lot of pause, slow-play, and repeats to understand the notes.

Here at [2:30](https://youtu.be/KNIhd3-TpNU?t=149) I believe he is playing

```
sa re ga ma re sa re
sa re ga ma re sa re
ni re sa ni da ni pa da ni sa re
```

However, when he sings out the saptak at [2:50](https://youtu.be/KNIhd3-TpNU?t=170), the first two lines are same, but last third one has an added `sa ni`, i.e.

```
ni re sa ni da ni **sa ni** pa da ni sa re
```

I do not hear the `sa ni` when Harsh plays it. I don't even hear it being played very fast (Harsh likes to add his own ornamentation, I've noticed)

And when I try to play it, I can only play without the 'sa ni', i.e. if I add it before `pa da ni sa re`, the tune sounds different.

Can you check Harsh is in fact playing with `sa ni`, or it is an oversight?

Comment: Hope my amended answer helps! I suggest the Sriharsha version over the Dave one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can hear the extra `sa ni` in the example he plays, but he makes it sound more like an ornament. When he sings the example the notes sound much more deliberate.

In my experience when musicians are both playing and talking in a video it's much better to orientate yourself to what they are playing rather than what they are saying (or singing).

Comment: As a start, I'll follow what I hear. Later on I'll attempt ornamentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Dave is taking the wrong tonic (sa) 
So (in my view) all his note (names) are wrong.
Or if you prefer : off by 3.

That is where he starts

> dha sa ga sa ma sa re ni

I'd say it should really be

> sa ga pa ga dha ga ma re

Now you can do that to sing/play in the same (absolute) key as the original. But absolute  do-re-mi or fixed do solfege is completely wrong way of doing Indian music.

---

## Added later

I just found this version of [Sriharsha Ramkumar](https://youtu.be/_mRnxQ1YDmk)

He doesn't make the wrong-sa mistake of Dave. 
However he skips the lead-up so...
Dave 0:34 flute, swaras: 0:45 given as

> ga dha pa pa ma ma ga re sa re ma ga

Becomes Sriharsha 3min 44 sec

> pa sa ni ni dha dha pa ma ga ma dha pa

Note: He's giving S Indian (carnatic) style note names.

Comment: I'd say his note names are correct. He's playing a Bansuri  with sa=A-flat. The beginning is in what Westerners would call F minor which I think is throwing you off: the second note (Ab) is sa and not the first (F). Also you're not answering  the question which was about a later point in the tune

Comment: @piedpiper your facts are correct but you are insisting on a [fixed-do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge) formulation which is at least disputably useful in a western context and utterly wrong in an Indian one. In an Indian context – always movable do – if I have an Ab flute and I want to play an F piece I should transpose the piece up 3 semitones before assigning do-re-mi (sa-re-ga)  names.  The real question is that in OP's [first link](https://youtu.be/Umqb9KENgmk) is the very first note a minor 6th or the tonic?

Comment: For Harsh Dave the first note is the minor sixth (dha). Since he's the expert here, I accept his version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP question about the heard extra notes.

Comment: @davidbowling True; it doesn't. But which is worse: right answer reinforcing wrong methodology/practice? Or calling out a misguided and misguiding practice? I think saying an F min piece is in Ab major is questionable even in western tonal music. In Indian music which is much more overwhelmingly tonal – one can attend a whole night concert in which the tanpura never stops – is way more outrageous.

Comment: How does any of that prevent you from answering the question of the extra heard notes?

Comment: @davidbowling : And I don't think this discussion is helping OP. If you disapprove you're welcome to downvote. If you think there is some merit to continuing we can head out to meta. For myself – I know a bit of Indian music but almost nothing of flute – I will consult more expert flautists if (to use piano metaphor) if a C flute playing minor is played in A min at a novice level in order to avoid "black notes"

Comment: @davidbowling Correct version added

Comment: @Rusi Thank you for this link. It is very comprehensive.

Comment: @marium So which tutorial are you working with?Sriharsha? Dave?

Comment: @Rusi I'll finish Dave (was half-way through). For a deeper-dive I will work with Shriharsha.

Comment: @Rusi Please see new question. Will start learning from the video in the next few days or so, https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/88542/convert-hindustani-bansuri-notes-to-carnatic-venu-notes